# SSIS - Derived Column Replace NULL Values with empty string

Tags: ssis, null, etl, derived-column

```
ISNULL([1 (Q1_1) ])? "": [1 (Q1_1) ]
```

When I drag the column under the Columns box in the top left, that's how my column appears,

`[1 (Q1_1) ]`.

Why is my expression not working? I want to replace `NULL` values with an empty string.

Comment: Are you replacing the existing `[1 (Q1_1) ]` or have you defined a new column?

Answer (score 2):

By default, if you just add the above expression into a Derived Column Expression, SSIS will give the column a name like `Derived Column 1` For debugging purposes, I prefer this although I tend to rename the column into something so I know this value was computed from the data flow task.

## Set up

I have an OLE DB Source -> Derived Column -> Derived Column. The second derived column is simply an anchor point for a data viewer

### OLE DB Source

I use a query as my source to test your expression. The actual source does not matter here but I find a direct query is the easiest for people to reproduce in their environment.

```
SELECT
    D.col as [1 (Q1_1) ]
FROM
(
    VALUES ('ABC')
    ,(NULL)
   ,('Pickles')
   ,('More pickles')
   ,('NULL')
)D(col);
```

I have 5 values, 4 strings and one instance of `NULL`. The final null is simply the word representation of the letter N-U-L-L and not the NULL *value*. I've had debugging sessions where the literal text was at play and not the null placeholder.

### Derived Column

- Derived Column Name: Derived Column 1
- Derived Column:
- Expression: ISNULL([1 (Q1_1) ]) ? "" : [1 (Q1_1) ]
- Data Type: Unicode string [DT_WSTR]
- Length: 12

### Derived Column 1

Nothing set in here but this allows me to put a Data Viewer between the two components and when I run, this is what I see

[image]

As expected, the resulting value in the second column for the second row is an empty. The second column for the other 4 rows are a repeat of the value in the first column.

Now that I know that works as expected, if I toggle the `<add as new column>` to `Replace '1 (Q1_1) '` and re-run, I should see the same expected values, this time in the "original" column